# Why can I hit my extranet site with chrome and not IE?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke-6

Yesterday we launched our new extranet site and for some reason I cannot access it from home with Internet Exporer. I can hit it from home with chrome and Mozilla. What can be causing this issue?

**Edited**
I tried flishing the dns of my home PC. I have also tried an IIS reset on the remote server that iis and the site is installed on.

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you see an error message? Which IE and Windows version are you using? Have you tried watching the request in Fiddler?

Comment: @EricLaw Fiddler shows me that it is reaching the login page, then instead of prompting me with the windows login it dies. I am using IE9 and using windows 7 on my home PC. The error is Internet Explorer can not display the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

What authentication schemes does the server offer in its WWW-Authenticate header? My first guess is that it's offering `Negotiate` and you're hitting the problem described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/06/integrated-windows-authentication-kerberos-ntlm-http-400-error-for-16kb-authorization-header.aspx

If you disable the Integrated Windows Authentication feature in the IE Advanced Settings (and restart) you can verify if that's the issue.

If not, what security zone is the page in, and are your IE security settings set to the defaults? By default, the Internet Zone will prompt for credentials that would have been silently submitted if the target site were in the Intranet zone.